# Vb script to enable file sharing between computers not working

Tags: vbscript

This script is not woking any help is appreciated.

I tried longer wait time to no effect and I watched the FDResPub in services, but it never stopped.

I expected it to stop and then restart. I made a .bat file that works fine, but I wanted a way to do it with VBScript. Anyway, these are all the details I can provide at the moment.

---

'========= Code to Run as Administrator ====================

```
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'Pass a bogus argument, say [ uac]
 objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
  WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1
 Else
```

'============================================================
'Add your code here

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
oShell.run "cmd sc.exe stop FDResPub"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.run "cmd sc.exe start FDResPub"
Set oWmg = GetObject("winmgmts:")
strWndprs = "select * from Win32_Process where name='cmd.exe'"
Set objQResult = oWmg.Execquery(strWndprs)
For Each objProcess In objQResult
intReturn = objProcess.Terminate(1)
Next
MsgBox "Connections Restored"
```

Comment: Please put code markers (three backticks) around your code. Also please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your batch file works because everything is running synchronously. By default, the [Run method](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp) does not wait for the process to complete. Add the appropriate argument to make it wait and then you won't need the `Sleep` command at all. Also, run `sc.exe` directly. There's no need to run Cmd. There's also no need to kill Cmd. You've overcomplicated a simple task.